# How reload CSS in svelte component without reloading page?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, svelte, livereload

I use live reload on my Rails app. In sprocket CSS (normal mode), change CSS in code make a refrech css in browser without reloading page.

I add Svelte in my rails app and now, if I change CSS in component => it will reload all page.

There is a method to detect when css change, just refrech style without reloading page ?